# SQL. How to select multiple rows by using the MIN and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
ID UserId Name   Amount  RewardId
----------------------------
1  1      James  10.00   1
2  1      James  10.00   2
3  1      James  10.00   3
4  2      Dave   20.00   1
5  2      Dave   20.00   3
6  3      Lim    15.00   2
```

I'm trying to insert to another table, and this is the result that i'm struggling with:

```
Tbl1ID  RewardId
------------------
1       1
1       2
1       3
4       1
4       3
6       2
```

I'm trying to get the MIN(ID) of each person and select all the RewardId that belong to that person.

Comment: What is the query you are currently trying to use?

Comment: What have tried so far and what was the problem?

Comment: If you `select min(id) as id` as you suggest, then `group by rewardId` it should give you what you want.  Because `rewardid` is not unique, it will give you 3 rows each with the `minid`

Comment: Select MIN(Id), ??? From Tbl1 Group by Name, Amount
Got no idea how to the reward. If i group by, the result is wrong

Comment: Assuming everyone has one unique name, what do you want in the result table ?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1408c/2

Comment: @JohnWoo just did all your work for you.  excellent answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a simple self join to get the minimum id value per userid/rewardid combination;

```
SELECT MIN(a.id) Tbl1ID, b.RewardId
FROM mytable a
JOIN mytable b
  ON a.name = b.name
GROUP BY b.userid, b.rewardid
ORDER BY tbl1id, rewardid;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd805/1).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running SQL Server 2008+, you can simplify it by using Window Function.

```
INSERT INTO AnotherTable (Tbl1ID, RewardID)
SELECT MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Name),
       RewardID
FROM   SourceTable
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1408c0/4)

Comment: Trying to figure out your solution. Not too sure how Partition By works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT tbl1id,RewardID From
table1 S JOIN
(
SELECT MIN(ID) as tbl1id,Name FROM table1 GROUP BY Name
) T ON T.Name = S.Name
ORDER BY tbl1id
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a078/10)**

*Output:*

---

```
    Tbl1ID  RewardId
    ----------------
    1       1
    1       2
    1       3
    4       1
    4       3
    6       2
```

If you want insert into new table then try this out

```
Insert into Newtable (tbl1id,RewardID)
SELECT tbl1id,RewardID from
table1 S JOIN
(
SELECT MIN(ID) as tbl1id,Name
FROM table1
GROUP BY Name
) T ON T.Name = S.Name

ORDER BY tbl1id;
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/72d53/4)**